# Binary search goes into infinite loop

Tags: python-3.x, binary-search

I'm trying to find if a number is a perfect square. I have a simple binary search algorithm to do this, which ends up going into an infinite loop. I can't seem to find a way around this. Can someone help me with this.

```
def isPerfectSquare(self, num):
        """
        :type num: int
        :rtype: bool
        """
        if num < 1:
            return False
        start, end = 1, num
        while start <= end:
            mid = (end - start)//2
            if mid * mid == num:
                return True
            elif mid * mid < num:
                start = mid + 1
            else:
                end = mid
        return False
```

Comment: Put a `print(start, mid, end)` as the second line of your while... that should make it fairly obvious...

Comment: @JonClements I understand what is happening, just can't seem to find a way to fix it. Can you help with that?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include that - describe what you know it is and that the issue is you can't figure out how to fix it? It'll save anyone wanting to answer to guess at what your exact problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I kind of found the problem,
This is line of code which ends up with the wrong mid,

`mid = (end - start)//2`

Since we actually want a mid that is in the correct half, the code will be,

`mid = start + (end - start) // 2`
This fixes it.